# How do I fix failed to retrieve mirrorlist data loop in arch kde?

Tags: linux, archlinux, kde-plasma, arch

I'm running into an issue where booting up into arch KDE, my display will freeze for a few minutes before my icon dock loads, but none of the applications work. I believe it has something to do with my network configuration.

It also won't let me run commands such as nmcli and ifconfig

When plugged into ethernet, there is no internet connection. Same with wifi.
After rebooting the machine yesterday about 10 different times I got it to work fine. But today, I'm running into the same issue.

The error from jounalctl -ef

```
Starting Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector 
error: failed to retrieve mirrorlist data: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
reflector.service: Main process ecitied, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
reflector.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

From journalctl -ef it just keeps looping failed to retrieve mirrorlist data.

If you need more logs from other commands let me know.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux questions should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: *"Temporary failure in name resolution"* is the operative message. Your computer cannot resolve host names into IP addresses. This is a network setup issue (may be a driver problem, etc..) The [Archlinux Wiki - Network configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration) is a great resource. Also, you should not have auto-refresh set on your repos (for reasons just as this)

Comment: Your question is appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).